# Snowflake: copy into table from external stage: add file name and line number into the table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table created

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE EMPLOYEE_SKILL
(
    FILE_NAME_FULL_S3_PATH VARCHAR(),
    LINE_NUMBER VARCHAR(), 
    SKILL_ID NUMBER,
    EMP_ID NUMBER,
    SKILL_NAME VARCHAR(50),
    SKILL_LEVEL VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Note that I have added two columns `FILE_NAME_FULL_S3_PATH` and `LINE_NUMBER`. I want these two details of the data ingestion also.

I am trying to ingest into the above table from a 1000 files inside an s3 bucket

I am using this command

```
copy into EMPLOYEE_SKILL
    from s3://test_bucket/emp/ credentials=(aws_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' aws_secret_key='YYYYYYYYYY')
    file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|'skip_header = 1)
    on_error = 'continue';
```

How to make sure the first two columns are added automatically? The s3 full path of the file and also the line number

Comment: You would need to change your COPY INTO to use a SELECT statement. The metadata columns you need are documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html

Comment: I'm guessing the copy into command is not picking up the new fields? Could you try selecting from the @stage referencing the columns via $1,$2 etc and see if you can see the new columns?

Comment: How can we add column names instead $1,$2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do something like this

```
copy into EMPLOYEE_SKILL(FILE_NAME_FULL_S3_PATH,
    LINE_NUMBER, 
    SKILL_ID,
    EMP_ID,
    SKILL_NAME,
    SKILL_LEVEL )
    from (select metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number, t.$1, t.$2,t.$3,t.$4 from s3://test_bucket/emp/ )t
    credentials=(aws_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' aws_secret_key='YYYYYYYYYY')
    file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|'skip_header = 1)
    on_error = 'continue';
```